# How to Pass continue url to Login Required Decorator

Tags: python, google-app-engine, decorator, login-required

I have `login_required` decorator as follows:

```
def login_required(function):
  """ Decorator to check Logged in users."""
  def check_login(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.auth.get_user_by_session():
      self.redirect('/_ah/login_required')
    else:
      return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
  return check_login
```

Now I have a `Page` (which is rendered by a seperate `Handler`) where I have an option for users to upload image which can be viewed both by guests and users. As soon as the form is posted it is handled by another `Handler` which uses the `@login_required` decorator.

What I want to achieve is passing a `continue_url` variable that I can use in the `check_login` function while redirecting so that the user gets redirected back to the same page after logging in.

Comment: Note that redirects in response to POST requests won't preserve the method - the redirected request will use GET, and unless you stored the POST body somewhere on the server before redirecting, the user's data will be lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically, it sounds like you want to pass an argument to the decorator when you use it. Python does support this. The basic idea is that `@decorated(argument) def foo(...)` is equivalent to `def foo(...); foo = decorated(argument)(foo)`.

So you need to make `decorated` be something such that `decorated(argument)` can decorate `foo`. There are several recipes for this. Here's one - make `decorated` a class with a `__call__` method, so that `decorated(argument)` is a callable object that stores `argument` and uses it when called:

```
class decorator(object):
    def __init__(argument):
        self.argument = argument

    def __call__(self, wrapped):
        def wrapper(args_for_wrapped):
            do_something_with(self.argument)
            wrapped(args_for_wrapped)
            whatever_else_this_needs_to_do()
        return wrapper
```

This can also be achieved with a plain function (and an additional level of nesting), with tricks involving `functools.partial` etc.

Comment: so you mean to pass the value i can simply use @login_reuired(continue_url) ?? Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 3):

The `create_login_url` function takes the destination url as its first parameter.  You can get the dest_url from the request object.

```
def login_required(func):

    def _wrapper(request, *args, **kw):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            return func(request, *args, **kw)
        else:
            return request.redirect(users.create_login_url(request.get_url()))

    return _wrapper
```

Comment: The pages are Routed through the webapp2.Route methodology which under get method shows the form in the template. However, the page has multiple forms & each one of them has an action="" fields defined that is a Route to the Upload handlers. So For example from Homepage.html where a user posts the form is redirected to Upload.html which basically is the UploadHandler which Validates and posts the form. From the UploadHandler if the user is not logged in he/she is redirected to the Login.html page.. So dont you think calling request.get_url() will return Upload.html instead of Homepage.html ?